# run application after installshield patch

Tags: installshield, patch

Anyone with installshield experience. I have this quick patch that will replace my recently installed exe. It works fine, no problem. However, what I need right now is to automatically run the exe after patch. How can I do this? Please let me know if you don't understand my question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After days of research, I finally found what I'm looking for. And I thought maybe it would be of help to others so I'll post it here. What I did was put an event when Finish button is clicked under the SetupCompleteSuccess dialog.(BTW, I am using Basic MSI). I put **DoAction on the Event column**, **IS_LAUNCH_MY_PROGRAM_PLEASE on the Argument column**, **and PATCH as the condition**. And the default application will be launch. I hope this helps to others.

Comment: Adding that PATCH condition means the application will no longer launch on normal install if you are basing your patch on a regular upgrade, but I guess this QuickPatch project is something different from Installshield. I never tried it.